# Do you click, tap, tab to or select a link in 2023?

Tags: terminology, technical, tech-writing

Considering the many ways in which people can interact with web or app content – and especially wanting to include alternative accessibility tools, such as screen readers and more – is there a "one size fits all" proper way to describe the action one must perform to "activate" a link (hypertext link)? I am editing a slightly dated style guide for User Interface elements, and this is what I saw:

> "Users can activate a link by clicking/tapping/tabbing anywhere within the target area of link text and associated icon."

Comment: Isn't the action going to vary by the users' device type?

Comment: I think you select a link by nabbing it with a pair of tweezers.

Comment: Switching to second person for the simplicity and immediacy: "Activate any link with a click/tap/tab."

Comment: You can tab to focus the link, but you still have to do something, like hit `enter`, to activate it.

Comment: "Tabbing" more commonly cycles through links, at least on older browsers. But "activating" a link does not necessarily mean opening it: it could refer to selecting a link, after which you can then choose to open it. Telling **how** to do something (select a link) is not the same as telling readers to do that thing. So do you have a particular context; want an exhaustive list like "clicking/tapping/tabbing" that mentions all the ways a link can be activated/selected/etc; do you want a time-traveller to tell you which is most common in 2023; or do you want an opinion which is best?

Comment: Maybe: *A link can be followed by navigating to its target area and activating it per the user device.* But, like, duh.

Comment: I think you can just say "click the link". Users of touch devices understand that tapping is equivalent to clicking -- their fingertip is a metaphorical mouse.

Comment: And there's no need to tailor your language to screen readers, any more than you would avoid saying telling an audience to "look" or "listen" because there might be blind/deaf people in the audience.